# Python - Removing a specific entry inside a document in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the following entry in MongoDB. I am using PyMongo and I used the `insert_one` command to store this into the database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId('ffffffffffffffffff'),
    "Drink" : "Lemonade"
    "Prices per dates" : [
        {
            "Date" : "02-22-2017",
            "Price" : "5.00"
        },
        {
            "Date" : "02-21-2017",
            "Price" : "6.00"
        },            
        {
            "Date" : "02-20-2017",
            "Price" : "7.00"
        }
     ]
}
```

I want to insert a new date and price at the front and remove the last entry. This is the result I am looking for:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId('ffffffffffffffffff'),
    "Drink" : "Lemonade"
    "Prices per dates" : [
        {
            "Date" : "02-23-2017",
            "Price" : "4.00"
        },
        {
            "Date" : "02-22-2017",
            "Price" : "5.00"
        },            
        {
            "Date" : "02-21-2017",
            "Price" : "6.00"
        }
     ]
}
```

**My solution so far**

I figured out how to insert an entry through python:

```
db.collection.insert_one({"Drink":"Lemonade", "Prices per dates": { "Date" : "02-22-2017", "Price" : "5.00" } )
```

I'm having trouble with figuring out how to remove the last entry only. Could someone help me out with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [the example for $push with $each](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#example-push-each). You can do something like this to push a new subdocument to the end of the array, then pop from the front of the array until its length is 3:

```
db.collection.update_one(
    {"_id": _id},
    {'$push': {
        'Prices per dates': {
            '$each': [{
                "Date": "02-23-2017",
                "Price": "4.00"
            }],
            '$slice': -3}}})
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error saying `The dollar ($) prefixed field '$slice' in '$slice' is not valid for storage `. What does this mean?